# Intercepting fetch calls

Tags: javascript

I've been trying for a good while now to intercept fetch calls. I have succeeded to intercept the call but then the original call doesn't execute. I had no idea what fetch was until yesterday and it was a long march only figuring out I couldn't listen to $.ajaxSuccess or XMLHttpRequest.

What am I doing wrong? I really don't know how promises work very well. I've tried to read on it.

The problem is, the way I do it I can successfully read the returned JSON but it won't be passed on to the original caller function. (FYI I want to handle the data AFTER the caller function does). This is what I have so far and don't know how to make it work:

```
const constantMock = window.fetch;
window.fetch = function() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      constantMock.apply(this, arguments)
         .then((response) => {
            resolve(response);
            if(response.url.indexOf("/history") === -1 || response.type == "cors")
               return;

            response.json().then((data) => {
               resolve(data);
               console.log(data);
            });
         })
         .catch((error) => {
            reject(response);
         })
   });
}
```

How can I make this work? What am I doing wrong and what should I be doing?

(I do not have access to the caller function as I'm injecting the code into the browser.)

Comment: Might want to take a look at [`wretch`](https://github.com/elbywan/wretch) wrapper library for `fetch()` that also has some extra middlewares such as [`retry()`](https://github.com/elbywan/wretch-middlewares#retry)

Comment: @charlietfl I should have mentioned I cannot use any external libraries for this one.

Comment: OK...well source of that library might also be helpful for you

Comment: @charlietfl Will certainly take a look at it, thanks!

Comment: do you have to use the window.fetch call or can you wrap it in your own function? 
e.g. 
`const myFetch = function() {
    // do other stuff before here with arguments
    return window.fetch(arguments);
}

Comment: @KeithMorris I need to replace window.fetch as I'm intercepting fetch calls. I'm injecting this code from the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar a while back, here's the module I wrote.

Notes:

- the `resp.clone()` is pretty important if you're intercepting. The response is a one-time use, so the clone lets you use the response *and* still return it to the original callback too.
- IMHO it's easier to return the original promise chain, along with your intercepter `.then` of course, and just be sure to return the original response in your `.then` after you clone it for your own purposes.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
const fetchSnoop = (callback) => {
  if (typeof window.fetch.qwerCb !== 'undefined')
    window.fetch.qwerCb = callback;
  else {
    var qfetch = window.fetch;
    window.fetch = function (req, init) {
      return qfetch.apply(window, arguments).then(function (resp) {
        if (typeof window.fetch.qwerCb === 'function')
          window.fetch.qwerCb(resp.clone(), req, init);
        return resp;
      });
    };
    window.fetch.qwerCb = callback;
  }
};
```

As I'm sure is obvious, this module is designed to let you register a "callback" function to be called on every fetch. It can only take a single callback the way I wrote it, but it'd be pretty easy to change my single named property out for an array if you needed multiple callbacks. Anyway, here's a sample of registering the callback:

```
fetchSnoop((resp, req, init) => {
  if (true /* test criteria if you're only looking for particular fetches */)
    resp.json().then(t => {
      console.log('my json', t);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sweet! What's that **r** function though?

Comment: Also could there be a way to make sure the cloned response is called only once the original one is called?

Comment: Oops, forgot about the `r`. I had another promise doing something else and that was the resolver for it. Removed it from my answer. Hmm, not sure about delaying the response clone. There is a [bodyUsed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/bodyUsed) property of the response, but no callback that I know of. Be a little crude, but you could use a setTimeout or setInterval to watch for the original response to be consumed.

Comment: Yeah, setTimeout is what I'm going for but thought there might be a more correct approach. I will take a look at bodyUsed. Thanks a lot David :)